# How to get Mysql SUM of multiple columns in database

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I want to calculate total products in cart for one user by summing values for each product in cart.

**I'm using this query :**

```
    SELECT *, SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY id) AS TotalProducts 
    FROM cart WHERE user_id ='$user_id';
```

**Getting error:**

> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY product_id
>   ORDER BY id)

**EDIT with DB schema**

```
id | product_id | quantity | user_id
1  | 37         | 2        | 23847
2  | 70         | 2        | 23847
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `AS TotalProducts,` <<< remove that comma for one thing, it's a typo.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: comma removed and still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the MariaDB syntax, and you didn't show your schema, but here's my shot at an answer:

```
SELECT c.*,
    SUM(c.quantity) as `TotalProducts`
FROM cart c
WHERE c.user_id = '$user_id'
GROUP BY c.user_id
```

Or, if you want a total per product, you could use:

```
SELECT c.*,
    SUM(c.quantity) as `TotalProducts`
FROM cart c
WHERE c.user_id = '$user_id'
GROUP BY c.user_id, c.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.*,
       (SELECT SUM(c2.quantity)
        FROM cart c2
        WHERE c2.user_id = c.user_id AND
              c2.product_id = c.product_id AND
              c2.id <= c.id
       ) as TotalProducts 
FROM cart c
WHERE user_id = '$user_id';
```

Comment: Why not just use a group by and sum? Also, a couple of minor typos: ```produt``` and ```as AS```

Comment: Yes you do have typos. Otherwise the function works but I'm not getting the correct result. The user has 2 X product_id=37 + 2 X product_id=70 and I'm only getting 2. I should be getting 4.

Comment: @SebastianFarham . . . Your original formulation has `partition by `product_id`, which this implements.  If you don't intend that, then ask another question and provide sample data and desired results.